# Attribute Error when using Specialized JSON-oriented Flask App Example

Tags: python, json, flask

I'm trying to get all errors returned as JSON for my webservice. I found the following snippet: http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/83/ which described a way to implement this. When I attempted to use it I get the following stack trace

```
127.0.0.1 - - [30/Oct/2016 00:27:57] "GET /401 HTTP/1.1" 500 -
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/thermostat/python/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2000, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/opt/thermostat/python/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1991, in wsgi_app
    response = self.make_response(self.handle_exception(e))
  File "/opt/thermostat/python/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1559, in handle_exception
    handler = self._find_error_handler(InternalServerError())
  File "/opt/thermostat/python/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1476, in _find_error_handler
    .get(code))
  File "/opt/thermostat/python/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1465, in find_handler
    handler = handler_map.get(cls)
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'get'
```

Source code using this sample app: https://github.com/domenicosolazzo/flask_examples/blob/master/json-oriented-app_example.py. Disclaimer: this is not my code but the sample I pulled from but I get the same error.

I need all errors to come back as JSON rather than the HTML the Flask defaults to.  Is there a better way to do what I want?

Answer (score 3):

I just ran the same issue as you did, find out that new version of Flask introduced the problem. Found this workaround from this [commit](https://github.com/rafaelcaricio/connexion/commit/e2b2a7cb5d0d627a00cca2e7cf6a905764afb569), just replace the following error handler assignment :

`app.error_handler_spec[None][error_code] = function`

by

`app.register_error_handler(error_code, function)`

Comment: Thanks! I'm migrating a Flask 0.10.1 app and this answer was a lifesaver!

Answer (score 0):

In flask/app.py you can find:

```
.. versionadded:: 0.7
Use :meth:`register_error_handler` instead of modifying
:attr:`error_handler_spec` directly, for application wide error
handlers.
```

So if you want to jsonify flask app errors:

```
for code in default_exceptions.iterkeys():
    # don't modyfy the dictionary directly
    # app.error_handler_spec[None][code] = make_json_error
    # use method
    app.register_error_handler(code, make_json_error)
```